# Listen to a suggestion item being selected

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using the monaco editor as a search field. I want to be able to listen to the event when a user selects a suggestion item. If a user selects the suggestion item using `tab`, or clicks on the suggestion, is there a contextKey or action that gets triggered?

Answer (score 2):

[UPD]: added arguments to command to get completion name in the trigger function.

Yes, there is a `command` field in `CompletionItem` (I didn't find anything like that in `CompletionItemProvider`). This means, that you have to add a trigger to each of your completion items. These triggers might differ, just create another one with `editor.addCommand`.

Here is the code example (and [here is a link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.37.1#XQAAAALLBAAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMpUO-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWS9TrQEnwCrtvS90ifgPqtYeCiXsXNyyJo2VbmKcHbhdNQ_k39vH5gmZMRn-Fk_w-faDPMEibxkEBgPT_FwB0bAxMWhyZj6NtSPZacMKQuWpa39aLOggsmJjKxAWbOseszYw_F_VzlKjE8arLukhS6-rhm0f_OA2jGmUaXG9pkuzH1y1717ulolqSqKkZ1m7WNpV9afN7cHnF6uHQWzhwjTyft38_3vfihdXou96clxXeByNnMp2UICr86vnpGF6tRaB7sHZW0m6-5yRMDoDg-dwfOuBUcgipwSYVXE8HyFgrCzbQUsuExKtDQp88JucZ0m9ae2ndblS07eeQ3N4ANSLgF95bnITNibsmMnyog8QZnW4qQ_FCBY36il9CbFFaiXz-M3r-uMp8NNTWCX2DKZYkdU3CeKDiEE6fTnpKq4r3MOgjDcQooSvxeUKEawUML3RraLBMKv0yL1kbhKEJ4Hg-AI57zynGXx7jOooEmajl45UHUXOA7wLm6ZRmFotvdPOlEdImBFYA4OWkRGfmUu1W0xuEPGgIVSyv6mEI--LOD0zF5HHCHlgcyAtZkyOVaipRZL7EgSc68x3gK0Y16hBH1iPw_mNidS962SWUcU7OcEj8MD2hIYPsVm5NpjWpB7MqM5LJYeLnWvw3Q_S7yX1_6KGws25w4hGxxMjuZLduPXX-VfW0) to the same code in monaco-editor):

```js
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: '', language: "json",
});

var commandId = editor.addCommand(
    0,
    function (_, ...args) {
        // here is your trigger function
        alert(`your command ${args} is executing!`);
    },
    ""
);

function createDependencyProposals(range) {
    return [
        {
            label: '"completion"',
            insertText: 'my completion',
            range: range,
            command: {
                id: commandId,
                title: "commandTitle",
                arguments: ['my first completion']
            }
        },
        {
            label: '"completion2"',
            insertText: 'my second completion',
            range: range,
            command: {
                id: commandId,
                title: "commandTitle",
                arguments: ['my second completion']
            }
        },
    ];
}

monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider("json", {
    provideCompletionItems: function (model, position) {
        var word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
        var range = {
            startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            startColumn: word.startColumn,
            endColumn: word.endColumn,
        };
        return { suggestions: createDependencyProposals(range) };
    },
});
```

Start writing `completion` to get completion items.

Comment: Thank you for the example. In the trigger function, how can I find out which completion item the user has selected?

Comment: @justadeveloper that's a good question that I couldn't find an answer to. I looked into source code for CompletionItemProvider. It seems that it is impossible

Comment: @ilesha, for what it is worth, I found this answer that might help with my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809562/how-can-we-get-which-completion-item-is-selected-by-the-user/75442654#75442654

Comment: @justadeveloper thanks you! I updated the answer with arguments in trigger function